# What is causing this Shibboleth error: SAML 2 SSO profile is not configured for relying party?

Tags: authentication, ssl, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am setting up Shibboleth on a Rackspace CentOS 6 server and it was working fine with testshib.org, but when I try to test it against the real IdentityProvider, I continue to get this error:

`SAML 2 SSO profile is not configured for relying party`

or more specifically

> **ERROR**
>
> An error occurred while processing your request. Please contact your helpdesk or user ID office for assistance.
>
> This service requires cookies. Please ensure that they are enabled and try your going back to your desired resource and trying to login again.
>
> Use of your browser's back button may cause specific errors that can be resolved by going back to your desired resource and trying to login again.
>
> If you think you were sent here in error, please contact technical support
>
> **Error Message: SAML 2 SSO profile is not configured for relying party**

I would like to rule out SSL as a possible cause -- I was testing my Service Provider without running SSL, and it worked fine with testshib.org, so I don't think it could cause this error but I can't get SSL set up right now so I want to know if anybody has seen this error being caused by a lack of SSL?

The main difference between testshib.org and this setup is that I uploaded my SP metadata file to the testshib.org server, whereas with my current Identity Provider I haven't given them anything. Would that cause this error, does anybody know? I was under the impression that IdPs can manage requests from anonymous Service Providers...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The real Identity Provider generally needs your metadata up front before you can begin accepting SSO sessions. The IdP will need to load your metadata, and optionally configure/release attributes to your Service Provider, which your SP may require to make an authorization decision.

IdPs can accept requests from anonymous Service Providers, given it is configured appropriately. I don't believe the Shibboleth IdP is configured to accept anonymous requests by default.

If the IdP administrator is open to accepting anonymous requests, there is more information on that configuration here: http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Problem-configuring-and-IdP-to-support-anonymous-relying-parties-td6750775.html

Comment: "SP may require to make an authorization decision", May i know how can we do authorized decision here after authentication.

Comment: Attributes released to the SP from the IdP are available as environment variables.